# Get access to clients data using API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to make a platform where client can sign up and log in using their Google accounts, and accept that their Google Analytics data will be used for calculations.

They should accept the use only once, and then the program should download and process the Google Analytics data every day.

Please point me in the correct direction for documentation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to create a project in Google Cloud Platform, then go to : API and Services > Library > Google Analytics API. (This is to get analytics from an user). Then you need to create a project inside Firebase, allowing email authentication and you will be able to do your task.